# Notice: Undefined index/isset makes values return wrong

Tags: php, html, if-statement, isset

So I looked around a bit trying to find people who had similar problems but couldn't find EXACTLY what I was looking for. I'm working on creating a register page to learn some basic PHP and at first I was getting the error "Notice: Undefined index" but I solved that by using "isset();" but that gave me another problem,

Note: Wouldn't let me post the image sorry.

http://img571.imageshack.us/img571/9176/h0nx.png

Note: I had it so that after you click submit and get an error it will repost values so that you don't have to retype everything.

isset makes it so that the values of the boxes equal 1 (true) after submission.

The problem goes deeper though:

```
if ($submit) {
if ($fullname && $username && $password && $repeatedpassword && $email) {
    //encrypt passwords
    $password = md5($password);
    $repeatedpassword = md5($repeatedpassword);

    if($password!=$repeatedpassword) {
        echo "Your passwords didn't match.";

        if(strlen($password)<6){
            echo "Your password must be atleast six characters long.";
        }else{
        //FINISH UP
        }
    }else{
        echo "Please fill in all fields.";
    }
}
```

}

If you look up at the picture you will see that it said "Please fill in all fields." even though everything was filled in, so something is wrong with my if statement.

I need to find a better way to get rid of the Undefined Index error because of isset(); returning values of 1 in the input fields and also I need your help to figure out why my if statement is failing.

First time posting here so sorry if I wasn't descriptive enough, thanks.

EDIT:

```
$submit = isset($_POST['submit']);
$fullname = strip_tags(isset($_POST['fullname']));
$username = strip_tags(isset($_POST['username']));
$password = strip_tags(isset($_POST['password']));
$repeatedpassword = strip_tags(isset($_POST['repeatedpassword']));
$email = strip_tags(isset($_POST['email']));
$date = date("Y-m-d");

            <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                Your full name:
                </td>
                <td>
                <input maxlength='100' type='text' name='fullname' value='<?php echo $fullname?>'>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                Desired username:
                </td>
                <td>
                <input maxlength='100' type='text' name='username' value='<?php echo $username?>'>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                Desired password:
                </td>
                <td>
                <input maxlength='100' type='password' name='password' value='<?php echo $password?>'>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                Repeat password:
                </td>
                <td>
                <input maxlength='100' type='password' name='repeatedpassword' value='<?php echo $repeatedpassword?>'>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                Your email adress:
                </td>
                <td>
                <input maxlength='100' type='text' name='email' value='<?php echo $email?>'>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

Comment: show the code of you setting the form fields, i am guessing you are doing something like `value="isset($_POST['somefield'])"`, `isset` just checks if it exists returning a boolean true if it is false if it isnt, not the contents of the variable

Comment: `$fullname && $username && $password && $repeatedpassword && $email` - where do you set those?

Comment: The problem is not `isset()`. It's the way you used it. - Or, the POSTed values are totally missing in the form.

Comment: I added that code you were asking for.

Comment: So if you look here http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php, what does `isset()` return?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is your problem (along with the other similar lines using isset as a value)

```
$fullname = strip_tags(isset($_POST['fullname']));
```

you need to be using isset as a test not as a value

```
if(isset($_POST['fullname'])) {
   $fullname = strip_tags($_POST['fullname']);
} else {
   //set some error notification for user
   $fullname = "";
}
```

also you will have to change this

```
if ($fullname && $username && $password && $repeatedpassword && $email) {
```

to something like

```
if ($fullname !="" && $username != "" && $password != "" && $repeatedpassword != "" && $email != "") {
```

Comment: add `$fullname = ""` to the else statement (edited answer to show), and make sure to actually check the values of the variable not just that they exist.

Comment: Thank you very much! Finally fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

This won't work, if you do `md5()` as the very first step: Try using password 'a' and you'll see...

```
if(strlen($password)<6){
```

and this line should be best

```
if($password!==$repeatedpassword) {
```

This looks also terrible

```
if ($fullname && $username && $password && $repeatedpassword && $email)
```

Comment: I didn't know that !== was a thing?

Comment: !== checks against value and type, where as != just checks value

Answer (score 0):

I always use small function, and calling it ifset...

```
ifset(&$var){
   if(isset($var))
      return $var;
   else
      return NULL;
}
```